# Kubernetes HPA behavior

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

```
  behavior:
    scaleUp:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
      policies:
      - type: Percent
        value: 100
        periodSeconds: 60
      selectPolicy: Max
```

we use the behavior above for hpa, and we expect the hpa doubles the # of pod every 60 seconds if the average CPU is above the target. however, we see it's actually slowly increasing step by step from GKE logs. does anyone know the logic behind this?

does it mean
"no more than 100% of instance being created in past 60seconds (which upscales the workload based on usage/request each time)"

or

"upscale 100% if the cpu utilization is higher than target cpu"?

environment:
platform: gke
version. 1.18.17-gke.1901

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

I tried implementing HPA using your configuration and it doubles every 60 seconds. At most 100% of the currently running replicas will be added every 60 seconds till the HPA reaches its steady state.

Sampleconfig.yaml :

```
behavior:
  scaleUp:
   stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
   policies:
   - type: Percent
     value: 100
     periodSeconds: 60
   selectPolicy: Max
```

So, there might be some other limitation issue that is affecting the HPA. For example, HPA has an additional limit on how much it will/can scale up.

Comment: thanks! just checking, what's your k8s version and are you running in any cloud platform or local?

from the decision log in GKE, it shows that it upscale few at the time. maybe I should file a ticket to ask google.

Comment: I am using k8s version -1.19.10-gke.1600 and running it on Google Cloud Platform. If average CPU utilisation across active pods is less than the target, the scaling up stops.

Comment: I see. thanks! we are using 1.18.17-gke.1901, and in progress of upgrading to 1.19. let me try again after cluster is upgrade.

Comment: Hi Jyothi. did you set the cpu target very low during the test? (>>> 0.5 x current cpu utilization). from my test and understanding, the value is the threshold that enforces "no more than $value of instances being added in past $periodSeconds". if the traffic ramps up slowly within $periodSeconds, there could be multiple decisions with small step each based on the ratio of current_cpu/target_cpu.

Comment: if you set a target that's smaller than 0.5 of current utilization, it will trigger a 100% upscale in one step and wait for $periodSecond until next one.

Comment: Yes, i have tested with CPU utilisation less than 0.5 current cpu utilisation.